# How to prevent datetimepicker from being trigger happy?

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker

I have created a pupup dialog containing an input element for selecting date and time:

> ```
> <input type="text" id="timepicker1"/>
> ```

Every time the dialog is opened or when I switch to another application with alt+tab and then back to the browser again, the datetimepicker is being popped up.

Any ideas how to stop this from happening?

The date and time selector should only be activated when clicking on the input element.

Thanks!

```
function showCustomDialog(chartType){

    var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog">\
            <p></p>\
            <p>Select time frame to chart.</p>\
            <table>\
                <tr>\
                    <td>\
                        <p>Date: <input type="text" id="timepicker1"/>&nbsp;during&nbsp;</p>\
                    </td>\
                    <td>\
                        <select>\
                            <option value="0.25">15 Minutes</option>\
                            <option value="0.5">30 Minutes</option>\
                            <option value="1">1 Hour</option>\
                            <option value="2">2 Hours</option>\
                        </select>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>\
            </table>\
            <script>\
                    $("#timepicker1").datetimepicker({\
                        minDate: new Date(new Date() - 604800000),\
                        maxDate: new Date()\
                    });\
            </script>\
        </div>');

    NewDialog.dialog({
      height: 250,
      width: 650,
      modal: true,
      title: 'Process: '+$("#processTitle").text(),
      buttons: {
        "Create Chart": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( NewDialog ).remove();
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        $( NewDialog ).remove();
      }
    }).position({
       my: "center",
       at: "center",
       of: window
    });
}
```

.. and some screen shots for illustration purposes

**Popup dialog**

[image]

**datetimepicker**

[image]

The popup dialog is created from a menu
[image]

Comment: Is your date time picker called on key press or on click event?

Comment: Its created by a click event from a menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested,

I solved this issue by adding this to the datetimepicker

> showOn: "button",

And here is the working code:

```
function showCustomDialog(chartType){

    var NewDialog = $('<div id="MenuDialog">\
            <p></p>\
            <p>Select time frame to chart.</p>\
            <table>\
                <tr>\
                    <td>\
                        <p>Date Time: <input type="text" id="timepicker1" value=""/>&nbsp;Time Frame:&nbsp;</p>\
                    </td>\
                    <td>\
                        <select id="datetimeselect">\
                            <option value="0.25">15 Minutes</option>\
                            <option value="0.5">30 Minutes</option>\
                            <option value="1">1 Hour</option>\
                            <option value="2">2 Hours</option>\
                        </select>\
                    </td>\
                </tr>\
            </table>\
            <p></p>\
            <script>\
                    $("#timepicker1").datetimepicker({\
                        showOn: "button",\
                        minDate: new Date(new Date() - 604800000),\
                        maxDate: new Date()\
                    });\
            </script>\
        </div>');

    NewDialog.dialog({
      height: 300,
      width: 650,
      modal: true,
      title: 'Process: SomeProcess here',//+$("#processTitle").text(),
      buttons: {
        "Create Chart": function() {
          var bValid = true;
          allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( NewDialog ).remove();
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        $( NewDialog ).remove();
      }
    }).position({
       my: "center",
       at: "center",
       of: window
    });
}
```